# Why only the security settings of the boundary descriptor is not enough?

Tags: c++, winapi

Windows 7

I am reading the [Windows via C\C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663777) book. I try to understand how to work the security settings of the boundary descriptor, private namespace, and core object.

> The boundary descriptor gets a name, but more importantly, it gets a
>   SID of a privileged user group that is associated with it. That way,
>   Windows ensures that only the applications running under the context
>   of a user that is a part of this privileged group is able to create
>   the same namespace in the same boundary and thereby access the kernel
>   objects created within this boundary that are prefixed with the
>   private namespace name.

This is the simple code sample of creating a core object in the private namespace (from the book):

```
void CheckInstances() {

   // Create the boundary descriptor
   g_hBoundary = CreateBoundaryDescriptor(g_szBoundary, 0);

   // Create a SID corresponding to the Local Administrator group
   BYTE localAdminSID[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
   PSID pLocalAdminSID = &localAdminSID;
   DWORD cbSID = sizeof(localAdminSID);
   if (!CreateWellKnownSid(
      WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, NULL, pLocalAdminSID, &cbSID)) {
      AddText(TEXT("AddSIDToBoundaryDescriptor failed: %u\r\n"),
         GetLastError());
      return;
   }

   // Associate the Local Admin SID to the boundary descriptor
   // --> only applications running under an administrator user
   //     will be able to access the kernel objects in the same namespace
   if (!AddSIDToBoundaryDescriptor(&g_hBoundary, pLocalAdminSID)) {
      AddText(TEXT("AddSIDToBoundaryDescriptor failed: %u\r\n"),
         GetLastError());
      return;
   }

   // Create the namespace for Local Administrators only
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
   sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
   sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
   if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
      TEXT("D:(A;;GA;;;BA)"),
      SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, NULL)) {
      AddText(TEXT("Security Descriptor creation failed: %u\r\n"), GetLastError());
      return;
   }

   g_hNamespace =
      CreatePrivateNamespace(&sa, g_hBoundary, g_szNamespace);

   // Don't forget to release memory for the security descriptor
   LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor);


// Check the private namespace creation result
DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
if (g_hNamespace == NULL) {
   // Nothing to do if access is denied
   // --> this code must run under a Local Administrator account
   if (dwLastError == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
      AddText(TEXT("Access denied when creating the namespace.\r\n"));
      AddText(TEXT("   You must be running as Administrator.\r\n\r\n"));
      return;

        } else {
          if (dwLastError == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
          // If another instance has already created the namespace,
          // we need to open it instead.
             AddText(TEXT("CreatePrivateNamespace failed: %u\r\n"), dwLastError);
             g_hNamespace = OpenPrivateNamespace(g_hBoundary, g_szNamespace);
             if (g_hNamespace == NULL) {
                AddText(TEXT(" and OpenPrivateNamespace failed: %u\r\n"),
                   dwLastError);
                return;
             } else {
                g_bNamespaceOpened = TRUE;
                AddText(TEXT(" but OpenPrivateNamespace succeeded\r\n\r\n"));
             }
          } else {
             AddText(TEXT("Unexpected error occurred: %u\r\n\r\n"),
                dwLastError);
             return;
          }
       }
    }

    // Try to create the mutex object with a name
    // based on the private namespace
    TCHAR szMutexName[64];
    StringCchPrintf(szMutexName, _countof(szMutexName), TEXT("%s\\%s"),
       g_szNamespace, TEXT("Singleton"));

    g_hSingleton = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, szMutexName);
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
       // There is already an instance of this Singleton object
       AddText(TEXT("Another instance of Singleton is running:\r\n"));
       AddText(TEXT("--> Impossible to access application features.\r\n"));
    } else {
      // First time the Singleton object is created
      AddText(TEXT("First instance of Singleton:\r\n"));
      AddText(TEXT("--> Access application features now.\r\n"));
   }
}
```

The boundary descriptor has a SID. User can't cross this boundary if he is not a member of descriptor's SID. But the private namespace also has own security settings (through the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)... And the core object (the mutex in the code sample) has the same...

Why only the security settings of the boundary descriptor is not enough?

Comment: Your error checking is broken.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This code is from the book.

Comment: It's still broken. You call `GetLastError` in the wrong place.

Comment: I still don't understand you. This is not my code and it works fine. I quoted this code from the book for clarity of my question reason.

Comment: Why the place of the `GetLastError` is wrong?

Comment: You have to call it immediately after the function for which you want an error code. And you fail to do that for the call to `CreatePrivateNamespace`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94002/discussion-between-andrey-bushman-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: > *At a guess, the permissions on the private namespace object exist solely for the sake of consistency*. 

I think you are not right, because for creating the private namespace *are necessary* the boundary description. I can't set NULL instead it. Therefore *I am* to set the boundary descriptor with his security settings. So, for the private namespace object I don't understand the necesity of existing of security attribute.

Comment: I added *UPD* section.

Comment: Someone has rolled it back.  For the reference of future readers, it consisted of a [link to a corresponding question on Microsoft's forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/5e3d26bf-3c84-4a00-bb00-90541112d5f1/why-security-settings-of-boundary-descriptor-are-not-enough-for-the-private-namespace?forum=windowssecurity).

Answer (score 1):

There are two interpretations of your question, and I'm going to answer both because I think they're both important.

- Why do private namespaces have security descriptors?

For one, because *everything* in Windows has a security descriptor.  Well, not everything, but all kernel objects.  Making an exception for private namespaces would likely be a great deal of trouble and would serve no useful purpose.

There may also be edge cases where the security descriptors are in fact useful.  A boundary descriptor doesn't allow for deny entries, for instance, and there may be scenarios involving impersonation where it is useful to have a security descriptor distinct from the boundary descriptor.

We can also speculate that Microsoft may have been thinking about forwards compatibility (the security descriptor might be necessary for a feature that they may wish to add in the future) and defense-in-depth (the security descriptor might one day prevent or limit exploitation if someone discovers a bug in the code that implements the boundary descriptors).

- Why does the sample code set a specific ACL rather than just leaving it empty?

Defense-in-depth.  We don't actually *know* that there is no way to exploit a private namespace with inappropriate permissions, after all; all we know is that we haven't found any *documented* way to do so.  For example, there might be undocumented functions (or security flaws) that allow you to fake your way past the boundary descriptor, or to change it.

I would *strongly* recommend that you always ensure your private namespace objects are given ACLs appropriate to their purpose.